# ORA-00936 : missing expression error with ALTER table table_name modify (column_name DEFAULT on null column_name.nextval)

Tags: oracle11g

I have added a new column to a table using:

```
ALTER table table_name add column_name number(8);
```

And then updated it as below:

```
UPDATE table_name set column_name = column_name.nextval;
```

And then I tried to modify column to a not NULL column as below:

```
ALTER table table_name modify (column_name DEFAULT on null column_name.nextval)
```

after the last query I got the below error:

> ORA-00936 : missing expression

NOTE - the new column added here is a Sequence.

Could you please let me know what am I missing here.

Thank you.

Comment: For `alte table` you have to specify **what** to do with the column. [The syntax is](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877__I2103924): `{ add_column_clause | modify_column_clauses | drop_column_clause | add_period_clause | drop_period_clause }... | rename_column_clause`

Answer (score 0):

Should have been:

```
SQL> create table test (name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> alter table test add id number;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test modify id not null;           --> this

Table altered.

SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> alter table test modify id default on null seq.nextval;  --> this

Table altered.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER

SQL>
```

---

Note that such a syntax won't work in some of previous Oracle database versions (for example, 11g). You should mention which version you use.

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry for missing out the version. My bad. It is 11g.

Answer (score 0):

I understand You don't have to specify 'ON NULL' in alter statement. Try following.

```
create sequence test_seq;
create table test_table (col_1 number);
alter table test_table modify col_1 default test_seq.nextval;
```

Alter statement in the last will automatically set column value to next value of sequence if null is inserted into `test_table.col_1`